# Grails Many to Many with BaseClass and tablePerHierarchy false

Tags: grails, many-to-many

Based on the [official example](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html) the following example will fail with

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Table mm_author_books not found
```

How can I map a many-to-many relationsship in grails with tablePerHirachy set to false?

```
 class SomeBase {

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false

    }
 }

class Book extends SomeBase {

    String title

    static belongsTo = Author

    static hasMany = [authors: Author]

    static mapping = {
        authors joinTable: [name: "mm_author_books", key: 'mm_book_id' ]
    }
}

class Author extends SomeBase {

    String name

    List books

    static hasMany = [books: Book]

    static mapping = {
        books joinTable: [name: "mm_author_books", key: 'mm_author_id']
    }
}
```

Comment: was that `mm_author_books` created?

Comment: How could I check that? Its a in memory db that I get access to after the grails-app started.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `tablePerConcreteClass true` instead of `tablePerHierarchy false` it works. As we dont use an abstract base class both mapping strategies will create the same DB-mapping. I therefore assume it's a bug in the current gorm stack. I posted an issue: https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/issues/112